# How to solve problem with Axios post request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

There is such a vue method:

```
methods: {

sendTrackerClientData () {

    return axios.post("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=tracking.data_save&key_id=00227220201402050613" , {
      tracking_data: 'some data'
     })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('post method is working!');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

}

Which is hung on a button click event
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

After trying to send data, we can see the warnings and error described above in the firebug.
Trying to add headers by type:

```
return axios.post("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=tracking.data_save&key_id="+ this.$store.state.tracker.trackingKeyId , {
   headers: {
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Powered-By': 'bacon'
      },
      tracking_data: this.$store.state.tracker.trackingClientData
     })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('post method is working!');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

It didn’t lead to anything.
Question:
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's break this down:

```js
axios.post("... lots of stuff ..."+ this.$store.state.tracker.trackingKeyId , {
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Powered-By': 'bacon'
  },
  tracking_data: this.$store.state.tracker.trackingClientData
})
```

The first argument you're passing to `post` is the URL. I'm going to assume that's the correct URL.

The second argument you're passing is this object:

```js
{
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Powered-By': 'bacon'
  },
  tracking_data: this.$store.state.tracker.trackingClientData
}
```

This is wrong in multiple ways.

Firstly, you seem to be trying to add *response* headers as *request* headers. Neither `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` nor `X-Powered-By` should be there. They should be on the server.

But they aren't actually being set anyway because you've put the `headers` config in the wrong place. The arguments for `post` should be `url`, `data`, `config`. The `headers` need to go in the `config`, not the `data`.

axios will set the `content-type` header automatically. In the case of your request it'll set it to `application/json`. However, that will trigger a CORS preflight OPTIONS request as it isn't one of the 3 safe-listed content-types.

I don't know what `content-type` the API you're using expects but *if* you need to avoid the preflight request then you'll need to set it to one of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain`. e.g.:

```js
axios.post("... lots of stuff ..."+ this.$store.state.tracker.trackingKeyId , {
  tracking_data: this.$store.state.tracker.trackingClientData
}, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})
```

However, the `data` is still being encoded as JSON here (so the `content-type` header and the request body don't actually match). I believe jQuery defaults to encoding the `data` as a URL encoded query string. The official axios documentation for doing that is here:

https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

However, all of this very much depends on exactly what format the server is expecting.

As you only have a single parameter it might be possible to do something like this:

```js
axios.post(
  "... lots of stuff ..."+ this.$store.state.tracker.trackingKeyId,
  'tracking_data=' + encodeURIComponent(this.$store.state.tracker.trackingClientData),
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }
)
```

To debug this further you should carefully inspect the headers being sent each way in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. Make sure they are exactly what you're expecting. There shouldn't be any mysteries here, you can see exactly what headers are being used.

Further, if you aren't clear on how CORS works and what can trigger a preflight OPTIONS request then you should do some background reading on that.

Finally, you need to find out exactly what format your server is expecting for the data. We can speculate all day about what the correct code might be but if we know what we're aiming for then there's no need to guess.

I would add that the jQuery example you posted has `tracking_data` spelt incorrectly as `traking_data`. That won't be related to the CORS error but it makes me wonder whether it really 'works'.

Answer (score 1):

The issue means server restricts cross-origin requests. Those headers you've tried to add should be added on the server side. There is no way you can make it work without modifying your server code/settings.

Comment: But if I have done a 'get request' without any problem.
http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2020/02/06/0023/2790/1571558/58/44348e7020.jpg
And I tried to do post request with jquery in Vue component:
http://joxi.ru/D2PgJPYhkaJEWm
All of those stuff works.
Considering those circumstances - do exist possibilities of server-side problems?